# Create a SIlverlight wrapper class for Runtime apps

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to play multiple sounds simultaneously on a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app using SharpDX but it has quite a few drawbacks (instability, difficult to maintain and an annoying background noise whenever the XAudio engine is running). I really want to use the `SoundEffect` class in the XNA framework but it's only available in Silverlight.

My question is, can I add a Silverlight class library to my solution, create a custom class which wraps around the XNA framework libraries and then use this custom class in my main Runtime project to play the sounds? Or is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a XNA class in a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML project and there is no way to write a wrapper (because that would mean referencing it in a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML project). You just have to find a solution that does not use XNA.

Comment: Yeah I tried it referencing a SIlverlight class library from a Runtime project, and it gives an error.
Guess I'll have to stick with buggy old SharpDX. It's annoying how Runtime is meant to be superior to Silverlight but lacks behind it in many ways.